# .wav file runs on VLC player but not on Windows media player

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic2, wave, voice-recording

I created a mobile app in Ionic2 using the plugin `cordova-plugin-audioinput`
and have successfully recorded my voice with a android phone encoded to `audio/wav` format. The audio string has `data:audio/wav;base64` as header.
After completing an `http` post request to send this audio string to a `node.js REST` endpoint the audio string data has successfully been received at server end point.

The node.js server end point converted this audio string back to binary data and using node file stream wrote to a disk file. When I try to play this disk file in windows media player it gives error. But VLC player runs it all fine.My business requirement is to get this file run on windows media player. Where I am doing wrong?

***Ionic 2 relevant code is:***

```
declare var audioinput : any;
        let captureCfg = {
            sampleRate: audioinput.SAMPLERATE.CD_AUDIO_44100Hz,
            bufferSize: 16384,
            channels: audioinput.CHANNELS.MONO,
            format: audioinput.FORMAT.PCM_16BIT,
            normalize: true,
            normalizationFactor: 32767.0,
            streamToWebAudio: false,
            audioContext: null,
            concatenateMaxChunks: 50,
            audioSourceType: audioinput.AUDIOSOURCE_TYPE.DEFAULT
      };
var encoder = new WavAudioEncoder(this.captureCfg.sampleRate, this.captureCfg.channels, this.captureCfg.format)        
        encoder.encode([this.audioDataBuffer]);
        let blob = encoder.finish("audio/wav");
        let reader = new FileReader();
        let audio : any = {};
        reader.onload = (evt : any) => {
          this.htmlAudioSource = evt.target.result;
          audio.src = evt.target.result;
          audio.type = "audio/wav";
          this
            .appService
            .httpPost('Nodejs url', audio);
          this.audioDataBuffer = [];
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
```

***Node.js Server side relevant code is:***

```
let data1 = req.body;
let dataArray = data.split(',');
if(dataArray.length > 1){
    let data3 = dataArray[1];
    data3 = new Buffer(data3, 'base64');
    fs.writeFile("c:\\temp\\testBinary.wav",data3,"utf8",(err)=>{if(err){return(console.log(err))}});
}
```

Comment: Did you try changing the config

Comment: What's the error the player giving you?  I think your problem is that you're saying that the audio file content is base64 but you're trying to open it as utf8.

Comment: Windows media player encountered a problem while playing this file. This is the error I get while trying to use the file. The file is in binary format. It works fine with VLC player.